# Macro to create new variable based on values of other variable R

Tags: r, variables, macros, variable-assignment

I'm trying to create a variable "Q7_1_r", whose value is based on the values of the existing variable "Q7_1", and then apply  the technique to multiple variables (similar to a macro)

In the example below, my data frame is called newfile. If I hard code it in with

```
    sevenvar <- function(var){
    newfile <- mutate(newfile, Q7_1_r = case_when(var == 1 ~ 0,
                                    var == 2 ~ 25,
                                    var == 3 ~ 50,
                                    var == 4 ~ 75,
                                    var == 5 ~ 100))
    }

    sevens <- sevenvar(newfile$Q7_1)
```

it works. This would mean that Q7_1_r is 0 when Q7_1 is 1, 25 when Q7_1 = 2 etc.I tested this by

```
`head(sevens)`
```

and was happy with the result.

The issue is that I have over 100 variables to run this block of code against, and rather than writing it 100 times, I would like to create a dynamic where it creates "var_r" based on the values of "var", and then do a one liner outside of this saying that "var" is "Q7_1", "Q23_4", "Q35_2" etc. (a bit like calling a macro)

I tried the following

```
    sevenvar <- function(var){
    newfile <- mutate(newfile, paste(var,"_r", sep = "") = case_when(var == 1 ~ 0,
                                    var == 2 ~ 25,
                                    var == 3 ~ 50,
                                    var == 4 ~ 75,
                                    var == 5 ~ 100))
    }

    sevens <- sevenvar(newfile$Q7_1)
    head(sevens)
```

but it failed. The issue seems to be with the code for the creation of the "var_r" variable. Can anyone please advise how this can be done without me hard coding the above 100 times? Thanks.

Comment: The usual way to do this is to pivot the data into long format (= “tidy data”). That way, instead of several column names create have a *single* column called e.g. `name`, and another called `value`. If necessary, you can then afterwards pivot the data back into wide format, so that you then have separate columns, where the column names come from the `name` column. [Check out the ‘tidyr’ vignette on *Pivoting*](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Please excuse my ignorance as I'm new to R and not familiar with Pivoting. Can you show me how it could be used in relation to my code? I'm looking to create new variables Q6_1_r, Q7_5_r, Q32_4_r etc., whose values would be based on the values of Q6_1, Q7_5, Q32_4 etc. I can hard code it for one variable, but it would be more efficient if I could do this for "var", creating "var_r", and then have a one liner calling on the code for a specific value of "var".  E.g. If I say var = Q6_1, it creates a variable called Q6_1_r, with values based on algorithm in code

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small function using `match` and `lapply` over the desired columns.

```
fun <- \(x, a, b) b[match(x, a)]
```

Consider this toy data frame.

```
df
#   X1 X2 X3 X4         X5
# 1  1  1  2  4  2.0184237
# 2  5  2  2  1 -0.0627141
# 3  1  4  1  5  1.3048697

v <- c("X1", "X3", "X4")
df[v] <- lapply(df[v] , fun, a=1:5, b=c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100))
df
#    X1 X2 X3  X4         X5
# 1   0  1 25  75  2.0184237
# 2 100  2 25   0 -0.0627141
# 3   0  4  0 100  1.3048697
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
df <- cbind(data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5, 12, replace=TRUE), 3, 4)), X5=rnorm(3))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Not sure if lapply would be the best. What you have written above would potentially fit if I wanted to take all columns within a range (e.g. columns 1-10), but it's not as clean as that. For example, I might want to exclude column 5, or column 7 etc. There is no pattern regarding the columns, so having code that works for one column that I could reapply by a one liner changing the column in question would be best. Then I could pick the columns

Comment: @Barry lapply is great, and you can also specify vectors, see edit. You could also use numerics `c(1, 3, 4)` but it's error prone